# Rails helper number_to_precision prints out incorrectly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got a spree store application and I've noticed prices being saved / displayed wrongly.

I see that it uses the handy number_with_precision helper. On inspection I discovered that:

```
<%= number_with_precision(12.212, :precision => 2) %>
```

prints '1221' rather than '12.21'

I've also tried adding 'to_s' to make sure it's converting ok but no luck.

Anybody find the same?

ps. I'm using rails 3.1.1

Answer (score 1):

```
=number_with_precision(12.212, :precision => 2)
```

prints

```
12.21
```

rails 3.0.10

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.10)
irb(main):005:0* include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
irb(main):009:0* number_with_precision(12.212, :precision => 2)
=> "12.21"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try

```
include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
```

// Edit:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_with_precision

Comment: irb(main):009:0* number_with_precision(12.212, :precision => 2)
=> "12.21"

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it could be a locale issue. Have you created or edited `config/locales/en.yml`?

You might have the number formatting options set to empty (rather than being absent), which could cause this.

Comment: this sounds fairly plausible as I'm using a custom en-GB locale - will give it a look